# Overlaid calendar with links to calendars outside of the site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, calendar, overlay

In SharePoint 2013 I need to have a calendar with overlays that are selectable. I also need links to calendars in other site collections.

By default, a calendar webpart with overlays has "calendars in view" in the upper left corner which allows you to select which overlay you would like to use. But I cannot figure out how to add links to this webpart page. You are allowed to add webparts to the forms associated with the calendar webpart, but then you would only see the links if you were viewing one of those forms.

If I put the calendar webpart on a new page I can also add links to this page, but being a standard SharePoint page I won't have "calendars in view" in the upper left corner to be able to select overlays.

I have also considered adding a script to the page in my second solution that provides checkboxes associated with each overlay, but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Any help?

EDIT: Found a solution. I edited the calendar webpart in designer 2013. I inserted a webpart containing promoted links before the start of the calendar webpart zone in the standard calendar view. The promoted links show up just below the title of the calendar webpart and just before the calendar itself.